# CakePHP: Connection between model and controller failed

Tags: cakephp, model, controller, connection

I've got a problem overhere with my newest CakePHP application.

I've made a model and controller for Categories.

Model: Categorie.php

```
class Categorie extends AppModel{
    public $name = 'Categorie';
}
```

Controller: CategoriesController.php

```
class CategoriesController extends AppController {
    public function index(){
        $this->set('list', $this->Categorie->find('all'));
    }
}
```

But when I visit the page I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object
```

When I add

```
$this->loadModel('Categorie');
```

to the index-function in my controller it will work.

So I guess the connection between the model and controller is not working but I'm not sure and I don't know how to fix this.

Please help me out.

thnx

Comment: maybe somebody should have told you that the singular of "Categories" is "Category" - then you would not need to ask this question :) because then cake would automatically do everything right. But you should still mark the correct answer by now.

Answer (score 7):

CakePHP uses the controller names singular variant for matching the model, and the singular of **categories** is **category**, not **categorie**.

Comment: Oh how stupid of me, I didn't realize that Cake is so sensitive for the English language and cause English is not my first language i didn't realize is category single is with a Y instead if IE. Thnx

Comment: If you are unsure about the English word, you can always use `Inflector::pluralize` and `Inflector::singularize` from any working view to have Cake display the proper translation it expects. Also see [the book page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/inflector.html) about this Utility.

Answer (score 3):

As @ndm said, you should use CakePHP conventions.
Your table should be called `categories`, then your model should look like this:

```
class Category extends AppModel{

}
```

And then you can include it with:

```
$this->loadModel('Category');
```

On CategoriesController you can use it like this:

```
class CategoriesController extends AppController {
    public function index(){
        $this->set('list', $this->Category->find('all'));
    }
}
```

If you want to name your table otherwise, you can make use of `$useTable` variable in controller to specify the name of the table the model will work with.

Answer (score 2):

You could also make use of the controller's [$uses](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3a%24uses) property:

```
public $uses = array('Categorie');
```